# Map columns in one model to another in Visual Paradigm (Database differencing)

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

I have an excel sheet with columns A, B, C.  I have a database with columns X, Y, Z.  How can I model the mapping from one table/model/spreadsheet/tabular-data-set to another with an ERD or ORM (or other) in Visual Paradigm?

To be clear, I'm not talking about designing a database or foreign keys.  I'm only trying to move/copy data from database to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to document in a formal manner the mapping between the excel (it's an artifact) and the columns you can do it in many different ways.

Personally, I would simply insert in the model the excel artifact, and document the mapping where I explain how the import process works (a stored procedure, a java process...).

Otherwise you could draw a component diagram with a `<<database>>` component and a `<<table>>` subcomponent, then you could add a link to the excel artifact and use a stereotyped `<<mapping>>` association between artifact and table to make it more visual.

Or you could simply draw a dependency between between the table itself (if you have an ERD) and the excel artifact, documenting the mapping in the dependency itself or in a note: not very formal but still clear for the stakeholder of the diagram.